# Are the names Jeroboam and Rehoboam Hebrew puns?

Tags: 1-kings

1 Kings 12:12

> Three days later **Jeroboam** and all the **people** returned to **Rehoboam**, as the king had said, "Come back to me in three days."

Jeroboam
יָרָבְעָ֧ם (yā·rā·ḇə·‘ām)
Noun - proper - masculine singular
Strong's Hebrew 3379: Jeroboam -- 'the **people** increase', the name of two Israelites kings

the people
הָעָ֛ם (hā·‘ām)
Article | Noun - masculine singular
Strong's Hebrew 5971: A **people**, a tribe, troops, attendants, a flock

Rehoboam,
רְחַבְעָ֖ם (rə·ḥaḇ·‘ām)
Noun - proper - masculine singular
Strong's Hebrew 7346: Rehoboam -- 'a **people** are enlarged', a king of Judah

Increase and enlarge people. Does this verse sound funny and ironic in Hebrew?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, due to the similarity of meaning of the names, they are probably throne names that they picked or were given in response to each other. They are both claiming that their nation is/will-be expansive.